# Python Pandas Column remove special character and arrange values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame like below.

```
    columnA                                                                                                                     columnB                         columnC
[['Beauty & Wellness/Beauty Mavens', '21', '17', '22'], ['Beauty & Wellness/Frequently Visits Salons', '22', '21', '25']]   GA_All_B2B_Visitors_Jan20       2020-01-10 to 2020-01-15
[['Banking & Finance/Avid Investors', '585', '455', '700'], ['Beauty & Wellness/Beauty Mavens', '414', '339', '467']]       GA_Oven_Page_Visitors_Nov2019   2020-01-10 to 2020-01-15
```

and I am trying to arrange this to like below and I got stuck from where to start:

```
columnA                                     cola   colb    colc        columnB                          columnC
Beauty & Wellness/Beauty Mavens             21      17      22      GA_All_B2B_Visitors_Jan20       2020-01-10 to 2020-01-15
Beauty & Wellness/Frequently Visits Salons  22      21      25      GA_All_B2B_Visitors_Jan20       2020-01-10 to 2020-01-15
Banking & Finance/Avid Investors            585     455     700     GA_Oven_Page_Visitors_Nov2019   2020-01-10 to 2020-01-15
Beauty & Wellness/Beauty Mavens             414     339     467     GA_Oven_Page_Visitors_Nov2019   2020-01-10 to 2020-01-15
```

my approach is like below but got stuck from where to start.
I first tried to split the values of the first column but it's not working.

```
df_seg = pd.concat([df_seg[['columnB', 'columnC']], df_seg['columnA'].str.split(', ', expand=True)], axis=1)
```

Can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) 
to be able to create a `DataFrame` with the content of both lists and join it with [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
new_df = df.explode('columnA').reset_index(drop=True)
new_df = (pd.DataFrame(new_df['columnA'].tolist(),
                       columns = ['columnA','cola','colb','colc'])
            .join(new_df[['columnB','columnC']]))
print(new_df)
                                      columnA cola colb colc  \
0             Beauty & Wellness/Beauty Mavens   21   17   22   
1  Beauty & Wellness/Frequently Visits Salons   22   21   25   
2            Banking & Finance/Avid Investors  585  455  700   
3             Beauty & Wellness/Beauty Mavens  414  339  467   

                         columnB                   columnC  
0      GA_All_B2B_Visitors_Jan20  2020-01-10 to 2020-01-15  
1      GA_All_B2B_Visitors_Jan20  2020-01-10 to 2020-01-15  
2  GA_Oven_Page_Visitors_Nov2019  2020-01-10 to 2020-01-15  
3  GA_Oven_Page_Visitors_Nov2019  2020-01-10 to 2020-01-15
```